# A cyclic group $G$ has only one proper subgroup and it is of order $p$ (a prime). What is the order of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

The best I could come up with :

$G$ consists of :

1. The identity $e$,
2. Generators of $G$,
3. Generators of the subgroup (say, $H$) which is of order $p$.

If order of $G$ is $n$, then there are $φ(n)$ generators of $G$. Since $H$ is a proper subgroup, all the $p-1$ generators of $H$ are different from those of $G$. And then there's $e$. So order of $G$ is $φ(n)+p$.

Comment: How can you conclude $G$ is finite  ?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 - every infinite group has an infinite order proper subgroup.

Comment: I think they are asking the order in terms of p

Comment: @Myridium That is **not** true. Tarski monster groups are infinite $\;p\,-$ groups (simple, btw), such that *every proper* non-trivial subgroup is cyclic of order $\;p\;$ . Pretty strange beasts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - If $G=n$, then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of $n$ such that $\langle a^{\frac{n}{d}}\rangle$ and $\mid a^{\frac{n}{d}}\rangle\mid=d$

So, $n=p^2$. Otherwise you can obtain more than one subgroup.

> - If $G$ is infinite cylic then we know that G is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\rightarrow G$ with $n\rightarrow g^n$.

We know that subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ has the form $n\Bbb Z=\{na|  n\in \Bbb N, a\in \Bbb Z \}$. If it has prime order subgroup we can find $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $pn=1$. This is a contradiction. Actually, we know that any subgroup of $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is infinite.

Comment: ...And if the order of $\;G\;$ is not $\;n\;$... ?

Comment: what does you mean? $n=p^2$ for question.

Comment: You begin your *answer* with "If something..." , and I ask: what "if something" isn't true.

Comment: you mean it is not finite ?

Comment: I mean that (1) You must first extablish or at least mention that it **must** be finite (with some hints you can leave the proof for the OP), and (2) then you can mention what is within the yellow frame in your answer.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I think question just for $\mid G\mid$ is finite. Otherwise, maybe we can just find example.

Comment: DonAntonio, again I understood you later. Thank you. I improved my answer.

Answer (score 4):

We know that $G$ is a cyclic group, and it contains an order $p$ element. It follows from [Lagrange's Theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem) that
$$G = \mathbb Z_{n} \quad \text{ for some } \quad n : p | n$$
We also know that the subgroup is *proper*, implying that $n>p$. It's also the *only* proper subgroup. If $G = Z_{ap}$ for $a \neq p$, then there would be a proper subgroup of some different order $a$-- specifically the group $\langle p\rangle$ consisting of $\{p,2p,3p, \dots ap=0\}$.

We have that $n > p$, and also that $n \neq a p$ where $a \neq p$. The conclusion is that $n = p^2$.

Note that this proof did not make use of the fact that $p$ is prime. If $p$ were not prime, then you would necessarily have more than one proper subgroup.

Comment: Why $G = \mathbb Z_{n}$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci - by stipulation of the question...? That's my notation for a cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Seems to be correct.

Comment: Because some explanations are missing, and it uses improper notations.

Comment: @EugenCovaci - a notation is not improper simply because you aren't familiar with it. [I'm not the only one who uses it.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGroup.html). The missing steps is perhaps a fair point, but hardly worth a downvote in my opinion.

Comment: I see why you write any cyclic group of order $n$ as $\mathbb Z_n$ as the algebraic properties are the same. But then by that logic, the subgroup $<2>$ of $\mathbb Z_6$ is no different from $\mathbb Z_3$

Comment: First, you have to prove G is finite, then use the fact that any cyclic group of order n is isomorphic to $Z_n$, to mention only a few poorly explained things from your answer.

Comment: I think Myridium has a point here. **any** cyclic group is either infinite or finite, and if it is infinite then it is isomorphic with $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , which is torsion free. Thus, if $\;G\;$ is cyclic and it has an element of **finite order** $\;p>1\;$ it then must be finite. Now, Myridium does **not** have to prove this. This could be one of the OP's works: to check the claims the answer contains are true. If he has any question about the answer he can check *and then* write back and ask for clarification. The downvote, thus, is unjustified. His notation is very widespread though I dislike it

Comment: @Myridium A more direct and justified (imo) critic to your answer: you've mentioned that $\;G\cong\Bbb Z_n\;,\;\;p\,\mid\,n\;$ , and then you write that  "If $\;G=\Bbb Z_{ap},\,a\neq \;$ there'd be a subgroup of order different to $\;p\;$"... **why**? You can either mention Sylow or the fact that abelian groups fulfill the opposite to Lagrange's Theorem. You've also *not* covered the case where $\;G=\Bbb Z_{p^m}\;,\;\;m\ge2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio - I honestly feel that all those details are very obvious and do not need explaining. I wouldn't bother putting them in a proof. We're talking about cyclic groups here-- the easiest class of groups to understand intuitively in my opinion. If $G = \mathbb Z_{ap}$ then $p$ is an order $a$ element. If $G = \mathbb Z_{p^m}, m \geq 2$, then refer to previous case.

Comment: @Myridium I can't honestly see in your answer any reference to the case $\;G=\Bbb Z_{p^m}\;,\;\;m>2\;$ ... What you mention in your fourth line (" then there'd be a subgroup of some different order $\;a\neq p\,$") can be taken as a vague reference to Sylow theorems, which wouldn't be appliable in the case of a group of order $\;p^m\;$, which needs a different approach. It certainly isn't necessary to prove *everything* in an answer in this site, but I think it is desirable to mention *at least* the basic facts.

Comment: @DonAntonio - let $a = p^{m-1}$. Then $ap = p^m$. For $m>2, a \neq p$.

Comment: @Myridium Yes, I know...and then why such a group would have proper subgroups of orders different from $\;p\;$ ? It is true (in fact, even *normal* subgroups of any order dividing the group's can be found), but I think it must be *mentioned*, if not proved.

Comment: @DonAntonio - okay, I suppose Lagrange's Theorem isn't trivial at all. I left a link to it and gave an explicit example of a proper subgroup of order $a$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the order of group should be $p^2$  as it is cyclic for every divisor we have a unique subgroup and $p^2$  has only three divisors  hence unique subgroup of order p.
Hope it works

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is actually good. Say $n=|G|$. Then an element is in one of the following classes

1. the identity;
2. the generators of the unique subgroup of order $p$;
3. the generators of $G$.

In particular, $G$ cannot be infinite. Also, $n=|G|$ cannot have prime divisors different from $p$ (Cauchy), so $n=p^k$ for some $k$ and $\varphi(n)=p^k-p^{k-1}$. Therefore we have
$$
p^k=1+(p-1)+\varphi(p^k)=p+p^{k}-p^{k-1}
$$
which implies $k=2$.

---

A different proof, without counting. Let's drop the assumption that $G$ is cyclic, which is not necessary.

If $G$ is infinite, then it cannot have an element of infinite order; but an infinite cyclic group has infinitely many subgroups: contradiction.

Hence all elements of $G$ must have finite order. Take an element $x$ of order $m$; if a prime $q$ different from $p$ divides $m$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $q$, namely $\langle x^{m/q}\rangle$.

Therefore the order of each element is of the form $p^k$.

Suppose that all non identity elements have order $p$. Take an element $a\in G$, $a\ne 1$. If $b\in G$, $b\ne1$, we must have $\langle b\rangle=\langle a\rangle$ or we'd get two distinct subgroups of order $p$. Hence $G=\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic of order $p$: a contradiction.

Hence there is an element $y$ having order $p^k$ with $k\ge2$. Then $\langle y^{p^{k-2}}\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p^2$: by the assumption on $G$, this subgroup cannot be proper, hence $G$ is cyclic of order $p^2$.