# A finite group with only one proper subgroup of prime order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If a finite group $G$ (we don't know whether it is abelian or not) has only three subgroups (two of them are trivial, and only one of them is proper with prime order). Can we say anything about $G$?

Here is a related question, but it assumes further that $G$ is cyclic.

[A cyclic group $G$ has only one proper subgroup and it is of order $p$ (a prime). What is the order of $G$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580433/a-cyclic-group-g-has-only-one-proper-subgroup-and-it-is-of-order-p-a-prime)

Comment: For starters it's a $p$-group.

Comment: The subgroup of order $p$ is normal.

Comment: I suspect that it's got order $p^2$. In which case it's cyclic.

Comment: The proper subgroup is cyclic of prime order and normal. The quotient by it is cyclic of primer order. That means $G$ has order $p^2$ or $pq$. But groups of order $pq$ have at least two proper nontrivial subgroups, Of the two groups of order $p^2$, one is cyclic and satisfies your condition. The other is isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p$ and has $p+1$ proper nontrivial subgroups. So $G$ is cyclic of order $p^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $G$ is cyclic of order $p^2$ for some prime $p$.

The proper nontrivial subgroup $H$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups, so is cyclic of prime order $p$ Being the only subgroup of order $p$, it is normal. And $G/H$ has no proper nontrivial subgroup, so it is of prime order $q$. Thus, $G$ has order $pq$.

If $p\neq q$, then $G$ would also have a proper subgroup of order $q$, which is impossible, so $p=q$, $G$ has order $p^2$.

Now let $y\notin H$. We have $\langle y\rangle\neq H$ and $\langle y\rangle\neq \{e\}$. Since the only other subgroup of $G$ is $G$, then we conclude that $\langle y\rangle= G$. So $G$ is cyclic of order $p^2$.

Comment: You (implicitly)  used the correspondence theorem.   That had me slightly snagged.   But now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not abelian,  then the center must be of order $p$ (since the center of a $p$-group is non-trivial).  The quotient by the center is of order $p$ (by the correspondence theorem).  Hence it's abelian.   The structure theorem finishes it.  It's $C_{p^2}$.